# MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr) - how does this convert utf-8 strings to char*

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

The question title is basically what I'd like to ask:

`[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]` - how does this convert utf-8 strings to char* ?

I use the above line when I attempt to communicate between c# and c++ dlls;
more specifically, between:

```
somefunction(char *string) [c++ dll]

somefunction([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr) string text) [c#]
```

When I send my utf-8 text (scintilla.Text) through c# and into my c++ dll,
I'm shown in my VS 10 debugger that:

1. the c# string was successfully converted to `char*`
2. the resulting `char*` properly reflects the corresponding utf-8 chars (including the bit in Korean) in the watch window.

Here's a screenshot (with more details):

[image: ss]

As you can see, `initialScriptText[0]` returns the single `byte(char)`: 'B' and the contents of  `char* initialScriptText` are displayed properly (including Korean) in the VS watch window.

Going through the `char` pointer, it seems that English is saved as one `byte` per `char`, while Korean seems to be saved as two bytes per `char`. (the Korean word in the screenshot is 3 letters, hence saved in 6 bytes)

This seems to show that each 'letter' isn't saved in equal size containers, but differs depending on language. (possible hint on type?)

I'm trying to achieve the same result in pure c++: reading in utf-8 files and saving the result as `char*`.

Here's an example of my attempt to read a utf-8 file and convert to `char*` in c++:

[image]

observations:

1. loss in visual when converting from `wchar_t*` to `char*`
2. since result, s8 displays the string properly, I know I've converted the utf-8 file content in `wchar_t*` successfully to `char*`
3. since 'result' retains the bytes I've taken directly from the file, but I'm getting a different result from what I had through c# (I've used the same file), I've concluded that the c# marshal has put the file contents through some other procedure to further mutate the text to `char*`.

(the screenshot also shows my terrible failure in using wcstombs)

note: I'm using the utf8 header from (http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/)

Please correct me on any mistakes in my code/observations.

I'd like to be able to mimic the result I'm getting through the c# marshal and I've realised after going through all this that I'm completely stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: UTF-8 is a variable width encoding, so yes characters can be expressed as 1 or more bytes. Check the Wikipedia article for specifics.

Comment: See [GDAL how to support unicode characters in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33295822/gdal-gdalratsetvalueasstring-how-to-save-chinese-characters-c)

Comment: See [GDAL unicode characters support in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33295822/gdal-gdalratsetvalueasstring-how-to-save-chinese-characters-c)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] - how does this convert utf-8 strings to char* ?

It doesn't.  There is no such thing as a "utf-8 string" in managed code, strings are always encoded in utf-16.  The marshaling from and to an LPStr is done with the default system code page.  Which makes it fairly remarkable that you see Korean glyphs in the debugger, unless you use code page 949.

If interop with utf-8 is a hard requirement then you need to use a byte[] in the pinvoke declaration.  And convert back and forth yourself with System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.  Use its GetString() method to convert the byte[] to a string, its GetBytes() method to convert a string to byte[].  Avoid all this if possible by using wchar_t[] in the native code.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I realised that I was so caught up in this issue of char* conversion that I blindly forgot about a more simpler wchar_t[] implementation.

Answer (score 15):

While the other answers are correct, there has been a major development in .NET 4.7. Now there is an option that does exactly what UTF-8 needs: `UnmanagedType.LPUTF8Str`. I tried it and it works like a Swiss chronometre, doing exactly what it sounds like.

In fact, I even used `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPUTF8Str)` in one parameter and `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)` in another. Also works. Here is my method (takes in string parameters and returns a string via a parameter):

`[DllImport("mylib.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void ProcessContent([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPUTF8Str)]string content,
 [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPUTF8Str), Out]StringBuilder outputBuffer,[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string settings);`

Thanks, Microsoft! Another nuisance is gone.

Comment: I was doing some stuff in `netstandard2.0` and saw that this isn't there... see this link for which target frameworks support `UnmanagedType.LPUTF8Str`: https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPUTF8Str

Comment: It was added in `netstandard2.1`: https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/595.

Answer (score 5):

[`ICustomMarshaler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.icustommarshaler) can be used, in case of using .NET Framework earlier than 4.7.

```cs
class UTF8StringCodec : ICustomMarshaler
{
    public static ICustomMarshaler GetInstance(string cookie) => new UTF8StringCodec();

    public void CleanUpManagedData(object ManagedObj)
    {
        // nop
    }

    public void CleanUpNativeData(IntPtr pNativeData)
    {
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pNativeData);
    }

    public int GetNativeDataSize()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IntPtr MarshalManagedToNative(object ManagedObj)
    {
        var text = $"{ManagedObj}";
        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        var ptr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(bytes.Length + 1);
        Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, ptr, bytes.Length);
        Marshal.WriteByte(ptr, bytes.Length, 0);
        return ptr;
    }

    public object MarshalNativeToManaged(IntPtr pNativeData)
    {
        if (pNativeData == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var bytes = new MemoryStream();
        var ofs = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            var byt = Marshal.ReadByte(pNativeData, ofs);
            if (byt == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            bytes.WriteByte(byt);
            ofs++;
        }

        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes.ToArray());
    }
}
```

P/Invoke declaration:

```cs
[DllImport("native.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private extern static int NativeFunc(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(UTF8StringCodec))] string path
);
```

Usage inside callback:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct Options
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
    public CallbackFunc callback;
}

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate int CallbackFunc(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.CustomMarshaler, MarshalTypeRef = typeof(UTF8StringCodec))] string path
);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you need to marshal UTF-8 `string` do it manually.

Define function with `IntPtr` instead of string:

```
somefunction(IntPtr text)
```

Then convert text to zero-terminated UTF8 array of bytes and write them to `IntPtr`:

```
byte[] retArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
byte[] retArrayZ = new byte[retArray.Length + 1];
Array.Copy(retArray, retArrayZ, retArray.Length);
IntPtr retPtr = AllocHGlobal(retArrayZ.Length);
Marshal.Copy(retArrayZ, 0, retPtr, retArrayZ.Length);
somefunction(retPtr);
```