# GDAL GDALRATSetValueAsString() how to save Chinese characters (c#)?

Tags: c#, string, unicode, gdal

I need help with GDAL. The string value with Chinese symbols is not readed/saved correctly (C#).

For SAVING grid value we using:
    private static extern void GDALRATSetValueAsString(IntPtr handle, int row, int field, [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string value);
method (c#) to save string value, **it seems that this method saves string as ANSI string**.

For READING:

```
private static extern IntPtr GDALRATGetValueAsString(IntPtr handle, int row, int field);
```

In. Example my string "银行Flamwood C2"
There is for methods to get value by pointer (use in GDALRATGetValueAsString metho):

```
var pointer = GDALRATGetValueAsString(GDALRasterAttributeTableH, row, field);
    a)    var b = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pointer);       // value: "㼿汆浡潷摯䌠2"
    b)    var a = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pointer);      // value: "??Flamwood C2"
    c)    var c = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(pointer);      // value: "㼿汆浡潷摯䌠2"
    d)    var d = Marshal.PtrToStringBSTR(pointer);       //Throws an error out of memory.
```

Q:  So how I can get Unicode string with was saved (so I can get using this *Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pointer)*) or most likely **how to save the Unicode string to GDALRAT** (GDAL RAT - GDAL Raster Attribute Table)?

GDAL version: 1.11.1

I tried to set CharSet = CharSet.Unicode but id does not helped, still get not correct string:

```
[DllImport(GdalWrapper.GdalDLL, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)] 
private static extern void GDALRATSetValueAsString(IntPtr handle, int row, int field, [In][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string value);
```

Thanks for any help.

**P.S.** If the GDAL source files need to be build again to save string as unicode string, then what build parameters and where has to be set?

Comment: Found this link: https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/rfc5_unicode. Maybe there is easear way (this article was written 5 years ago...)?

Comment: Also created ticket: https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/6168#ticket

Comment: do paste your solution

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289171/marshalasunmanagedtype-lpstr-how-does-this-convert-utf-8-strings-to-char describes a similar issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GDAL uses UTF-8 encoding internally when working with strings. That means strings must be converted to UTF-8 before passing them to GDAL. The same is valid for GDAL output strings - have to be converted from UTF-8 to local encoding before using.

C# uses UTF-16 strings so conversions to UTF-8 and back must be introduced:

```
public class EncodingConverter
{
    public static string Utf16ToUtf8(string utf16String)
    {
        byte[] utf16Bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(utf16String);
        byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.UTF8, utf16Bytes);
        return Encoding.Default.GetString(utf8Bytes);
    }

    public static string Utf8ToUtf16(string utf8String)
    {
        byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(utf8String);
        byte[] utf16Bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Unicode, utf8Bytes);
        return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(utf16Bytes);
    }
}
```

Going back to your problem, Japanese characters will be processed correctly if encoding conversion will be applied.

```
    public void SetValueAsString(int row, int field, string value)
    {
        string utf8Value = EncodingConverter.Utf16ToUtf8(value);
        GDALRATSetValueAsString(GDALRasterAttributeTableH, row, field, utf8Value);
    }

    public string GetValueAsString(int row, int field)
    {
        string value = null;

        var pointer = GDALRATGetValueAsString(GDALRasterAttributeTableH, row, field);
        if (pointer != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            string utf8Value = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pointer);
            value = EncodingConverter.Utf8ToUtf16(utf8Value);
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this first [Specifying a Character Set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b93s42f(v=vs.110).aspx).
Make sure there is a unicode version of GDALRATGetValueAsString.
Unicode version ends with a W e.g. GDALRATGetValueAsStringW.
ANSI version ends with a A e.g. GDALRATGetValueAsStringA.
If you import GDALRATGetValueAsString the charset is auto.
It is not clear which version of the function you are referring to.

Comment: Looking at the API of the C API http://www.gdal.org/gdal_8h.html it seems to be ANSI string which is returned, because it is a const char*. You need a wrapper function to convert the ANSI string into Unicode. E.g. MultiByteToWideChar https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx.